# Making a Recurring Profile but can't find Original Transaction ID despite having PNREF

Tags: paypal, transactions, payflowpro

I have a PNREF.

I am trying to create a Recurring Profile from a Paypal Transaction.

Under "[Example Add Action](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/#example-add-actions)", I have identical codes to "Converting an Existing Transaction into a Profile".

```
TRXTYPE=R
&TENDER=P
&PARTNER=PayPal
&VENDOR=Acme
&USER=Acme
&PWD=a1b2c3d4&ACTION=A
&PROFILENAME=RegularSubscription
&ORIGID=XYZ123
&START=12012013
&PAYPERIOD=WEEK&TERM=12
&OPTIONALTRX=S
&OPTIONALTRXAMT=2.00
&COMMENT1=First-time customer
&AMT=42.00
```

The only things change is "Tender" set to P, and of course "ORIGID" set to the PNREF I have.

Can I not convert an existing Paypal Transaction (Implying that it only works with Credit Cards)?

How can I fix this?

This is my results:

> RESULT=19&RPREF=RTXXXCADE4DF&RESPMSG=Original transaction ID not found

Answer (score 0):

Actually creating the recurring profile using the PNREF for the PayPal Payments is different from the credit cards recurring payments. You have to follow the steps given at the below link :

[PayPal Using Payflow to create Recurring Payment with PayPal account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938431/paypal-using-payflow-to-create-recurring-payment-with-paypal-account/25942177#25942177)

Comment: So I had to jump through some hoops and have Paypal configure my merchant account to enable "Reference Transactions".

 I am on "Action=G" and I am using an existing transaction token and grabbing details on that transaction. I am now getting this message: "RESPMSG=Generic processor error: 11607-A successful transaction has already been completed for this token."

Comment: Furthering tinkering with the CURL with "Action=X", I get this result "RESPMSG=Declined: 11455-Buyer did not accept billing agreement". Point is that I already had the billing agreement on a previous transaction and wanted to turn that transaction into a Recurring Billing Agreement. This should happen simultaneously as the transaction is completed.

Comment: Still no work around and still stuck on a wall. I would like to add that I am using a "Hosted" checkout page and that the express checkout capabilities may be out of my playground. Thoughts?

Comment: @Anraiki did you find a solution?